# Drupal 7 Calendar - How do you modify link from day number?

Tags: datetime

[image: calendar showing links on numbers]

When I click on the day number, it currently goes through to day page.  I'd like to customise this to go to a specific event page for that day.

I can't find a hook for this.  Is there one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The day page is generated by the day display of the view generated by the calendar module. You can customize this display as much as as you want - add header, footer, embed an attachment view, or otherwise enhance it:

[image: Calendar view - day display]

You can [disable the day display](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/81980/drupal-7-calendar-how-do-you-disable-the-number-link-to-the-day-page) if you don't want the links at all.

Replacing it with another page would be much harder, but it might be possible using the panels module.

Answer (score 0):

U need to customize it.
Firstly you need to put a alter in your template.php

```
function themename_preprocess_calendar_datebox(&$vars) {
  $date = $vars['date'];
  $view = $vars['view'];
  $day_path = calendar_granularity_path($view, 'day');
  $vars['url'] = 'events-and-attractions/events/' . $date;
  $vars['link'] = !empty($day_path) ?l($vars['day'],$vars['url']):$vars['day']; 
}
```

Create a view page that list the events , with a contextual filter of event start date. And provide that view path in  $vars['url'].